# Filter bad quality images from Sentinel-2 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

Working on an NDVI script in GEE I got some strange results. The problem is the quality in at least one of the products:

**Identifier: S2B_MSIL1C_20220711T103629_N0400_R008_T31TDF_20220711T124402**

[image]

Taking a look at the metadata I'm guessing the problem is detected in the "general quality" assessment:

[image]

So, if this is the problem, is there a specific way to filter out these bad quality products?

Or should I filter it excluding that date?

Comment: Include your script in the question. Ideally add a Code Editor link too (use the `Get Link` button). Make sure all used assets are shared.